# how to get ID vaule of a datarow in datatable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Actually, I have at **view.php**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","Persons");
$sql="SELECT * FROM Persons";
$rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

I tried  to databinding into a table, and everything is ok. BUT when i come to think about this:
 Then how to get ID of datarow that u put into table???

> |ID|Name|button (press it and user will go to **Lookup.php** and post  value for that page).

but if i let the button have the value is the ID of datarow then  on the table will have:

```
ID|Name|Choose
 1|John|(1)
```

but i want the button  have text is "+" and when user press, it will "POST" a value "1" to **Lookup.php**
Sorry, i am a application programmer. I am trying to convert my application to website application by coding.
Could someone give me a hint?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted id IF THE ID FIELD IS AUTO INCREMENTING like this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Or you can do like this

```
$id;

while($row = $rs->fetch_array($result)){
    $id= $row['id']; // You will get your id's here
}
```

Comment: i DID say" everything is ok". because i can get it but the issue is how to  post the ID value to anothe page when user press the button at the end of that row.NOTICE: the button must not have ID column's value.